# Notepad++ - Auto comment after closing a div to add starting Class/ID

Tags: html, notepad++

Using Notepad++ (or even an online tool would do that) is there a chance to automate to get starting Class or ID as a comment right after closing tag?
For instance this is original code

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Is there an option to convert it as

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">

        </div><!-- .col-lg-12 -->
    </div><!-- .row -->
</section><!-- .container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

My try, not tested but maybe works.
**SynWrite** app: write macro which

- finds "div" tag from caret position
- jumps word-next N times to place caret under id string
- calls command "Search - Select token" to select entire id string
- copies it to clipbd
- presses Left to jump to id start
- jumps word-previous N times to place caret under "div"
- jumps to pair "/div" tag using command `Ctrl+[`
- jumps after "/div" tag end
- pastes to caret position
- returns to beginning "div" tag

Then run this macro "Until end of file" in macro dlg.